# python livestreamer stream to image

Tags: python, image, screenshot, frame

The current code I have:

```
from livestreamer import Livestreamer
session = Livestreamer()
stream = session.streams('http://www.twitch.tv/esl_csgo')
stream = stream['source']
fd = stream.open()
with open("/tmp/stream.dat", 'wb') as f:
    while True:
        data = fd.read(1024)
        f.write(data)
```

I would like to get a frame out of this stream and cut it before storing as a png image

This piece of code works and it can be played with vlc player without a problem but I would like to attain a frame without saving files the entire time to reduce IO on hard disks.

I've tried to use cv2 but I couldn't find my way around the API after installing it https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide

Comment: Have you tried putting the data into an array and writing the array to disk only after a certain number of iterations (which you could keep track of with a counter)? Also, why do you have a `while True`? Is it to make sure there is data available? You can also deal with this using a try/except IOError statement.

Comment: @c.leather I don't want to store the stream, f.write(data) can be disregarded, I only need 1 frame. I can also do data += fd.read(1024)for some iterations but I need a way to convert data to images and get 1 image that I can store.